# Sed replace with conditions

Tags: sed

I have the following text file.

```
2017-03-01 10:57:50,892 [Thread-977] limits.compiler : ERROR - Error in formula Undefined_CountryDom
cannot get field LOCKS_CountryDom, String, CountryDom, belongs to Header, scalar (dynamic index: 172)
limits.compiler.LimitsVariablesException: cannot get field LOCKS_CountryDom, String, CountryDom, belongs to Header, scalar (dynamic index: 172)
        at limits.compiler.ExpressionHandler.evaluateBoolean(ExpressionHandler.java:170)
        at limits.compiler.ExpressionHandler.getBoolean(ExpressionHandler.java:266)
2017-03-01 10:57:50,700 [Thread-231] console : ERROR -  at limits.compiler.ExpressionHandler.getString(ExpressionHandler.java:700)
2017-03-01 10:57:50,892 [Thread-977] console : ERROR -  at limits.compiler.compliance.ComplianceCheckFactoryImpl.compileDefaultMessageExpression(ComplianceCheckFactoryImpl.java:107)
2017-03-01 10:57:50,892 [Thread-564] console : ERROR -  at limits.compiler.compliance.ComplianceCheckFactoryImpl.createOverflow(ComplianceCheckFactoryImpl.java:231)
2017-03-01 10:57:50,893 [Thread-977] console : ERROR -  at limits.compiler.compliance.ComplianceCheckFactoryImpl.evaluateTickLockCombinations(ComplianceCheckFactoryImpl.java:498)
2017-03-01 10:57:50,893 [Thread-977] console : ERROR -  at limits.engine.stream.TickWriterImpl.doMLCOperations(TickWriterImpl.java:2488)
```

I require the removal of `2017-03-01 10:57:50,700 [Thread-231] console : ERROR -`   such that the lines with time and `-     at` would be made similar to the lines without the time above.

The result should be something like this:

```
2017-03-01 10:57:50,892 [Thread-977] limits.compiler : ERROR - Error in formula Undefined_CountryDom
cannot get field LOCKS_CountryDom, String, CountryDom, belongs to Header, scalar (dynamic index: 172)
limits.compiler.LimitsVariablesException: cannot get field LOCKS_CountryDom, String, CountryDom, belongs to Header, scalar (dynamic index: 172)
        at limits.compiler.ExpressionHandler.evaluateBoolean(ExpressionHandler.java:170)
        at limits.compiler.ExpressionHandler.getBoolean(ExpressionHandler.java:266)
        at limits.compiler.ExpressionHandler.getString(ExpressionHandler.java:700)
        at limits.compiler.compliance.ComplianceCheckFactoryImpl.compileDefaultMessageExpression(ComplianceCheckFactoryImpl.java:107)
        at limits.compiler.compliance.ComplianceCheckFactoryImpl.createOverflow(ComplianceCheckFactoryImpl.java:231)
        at limits.compiler.compliance.ComplianceCheckFactoryImpl.evaluateTickLockCombinations(ComplianceCheckFactoryImpl.java:498)
        at limits.engine.stream.TickWriterImpl.doMLCOperations(TickWriterImpl.java:2488)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You don't really want to do this.... in your original input, your exceptions came from different threads, but if you had done the changes, your exception will be all from `Thread-977`, it provides the wrong information.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take the [tour],  learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
Assuming you do want to do that, how did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can group regular expressions within sed's famous substitution `s` function 
`s/regex/pattern/`. 
In this case, we use two groups `\(a_regex_group\)`and print one pattern, the second `\2`.

`sed 's/\(^[0-9]*.*-\s\s\)\(.*$\)/\t\2/'`

This chops everything which starts with numbers `^[0-9]*` followed by any arbitrary characters `.*` including a dash and two whitespaces `-\s\s` and leave the rest `\2` with a leading tabulator `\t`.

Comment: `/g` doesn't really have anything to do with grouping

Comment: Exactly! You got it ;) well done!. That's why I wrote: global `g` substitution `s` function `s/regex/pattern/g` **and** group(s) `\(a_regex_group\)`. Usefull hints are very welcome. There exists no `/g` only a `g`, but as you already checked out I have already mentioned it ;)

Comment: my point was that you can fully well use groups without the `g`, `s/this\(that\)/\1/` works just fine.

Comment: My fault, I thaught  you mentioned `/g` _doesn't really have anything to do with grouping_. Both will work, with- or without the global option. Nevertheless, you found the fly in the ointment ;)